# Laravel 5 pagination send to view with other variables

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I have this bunch of codes

```
$result= AccessControl::getUserAccess("/admin/users/user");
if($result==1)
{
    return redirect("/");
}
else
{
    $user= Users::Tenant((int)session()->get('tenantId'))->paginate();
    return response()->json(["Users"=>$user,"Access_level"=>$result]);
}
```

With the above, I kept getting an null for `$user` object on the front-end. But when I returned the`$user` object, that contains all expected for the pagination. How do I include `Access_level` as part of that to the user using json still?

Comment: Is it that I can't return any other thing with pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Access_level variables by using the appends method like so

```
$user= Users::Tenant((int)session()->get('tenantId'))->paginate();
$user['access_level ']= $result;
return $response->json( $user);
```

Comment: This only append to the url. What I seek is adding the `access_level` as a property of the object `$user`

Comment: Check edited answer, it gives a extra "access_level":1 , inside data of the paginated json result.